# WAS7 WebContainer java.io.FileNotFoundException: /services/TrainStation

Tags: java

Please assist us with the error below:
We have

1. Verified that the context-root is correct.
2. Verified that the url-pattern (CXFServlet) is correct.
3. Application Server is running.
4. Verified that we're using the correct port#.

But keep on getting the file not found error. Very confusing.

```
[2/8/14 5:00:15:506 CST]     FFDC Exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest ProbeId:573 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessorImpl@1ad81ad8
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /services/TrainStation
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:301)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:275)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)
```

Comment: Please provide further details, some background information and some code might help us...

Comment: I've recent configured my WAS local server v7.0. When I tried to use SoapUI using the url http://localhost:9080/zrun/services/TrainStation it fails with the error above. (1) I verified that my port number is correct. (2) Tried setting the Webcontainer setting: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility = true (3) Verified that the Virtual Host mapping for the Application Server, and Enterprise Application are the same. (4) Verified that the * mapping exists, and there is no duplicate ports.  My local server is running WAS v7.0 under Windows 7 32bits.  RAD version 7.5.5.3

Comment: So ask your vendor (IBM)...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my IBM RAD 7.5.5.3 was missing the ASPECTJ builders.  Once they were added everything started working.  So check your builders and make sure they are not missing if you're getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

All one's got to do is include a web container's custom property named

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.disallowserveservletsbyclassname

and set its value to "false".  In the WAS update process, there is a patch applied to it that would prevent accesing servlets directly from the request url, and that is what's doing harm.

When you setup this custom propety, the problem will dissapear.